# Is there any way to synch tasks and source code data between 2 TFS 2012 servers?

Tags: tfs, synchronization, mirroring

We use TFS to manage tasks and source code. We have 2 TFS 2012 servers. One is used by developers in India and another is used by developers in US. Is there any way to synch or mirror the TFS, so that at any point the both contain the same data (tasks and source code)?

If not immediate synch, then is there anyway to schedule a hourly, daily synch?

Comment: A TFS proxy is a way better choice than synchronizing your data

Comment: ANy link on TFS Proxy please..

Answer (score 6):

This is not a simple question nor a trivial project. You have two independent systems and you want to have the same data, which is practically impossible. You can get equivalent data in both systems.

My first option would be to collapse the two systems in one and leverage capabilities -- like TFS Proxy, caching HTTP proxies, WAN optimization hardware -- to reduce the latency impact for people further from the system.
This is preferable from a data management point of view and gives much more freedom to teams; it requires good infrastructure and network design.

The second option is to use TFS Integration Platform to synchronize the data. This requires accurate planning, but it is, generally doable. You need also to put in place some process, so semi-structural changes, say to Areas or Branches, is managed on one side only. Remember bug #42 for one system will be #89 on another!

I have seen implementation of both, and suggest to hire some good consultant to guide through the mine-fields, so to speak.

Comment: This solution is only to replicate code. What about tasks and stories?

Comment: What about mirroring http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa980644(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Also check http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2009/10/07/tfs-integration-platform-yes-i-can-do-a-full-tfs-server-sync-but-should-i-part-2.aspx

Comment: For anyone who may drops here. Integration Platform sync both code AND work items. Database mirroring is not a solution: it is a one-way sync, useful in disaster recovery scenarios.

Comment: is  Integration Platform sync a bidirectional sync?

Comment: Obviously, but see my answer.

Comment: The correct solution is to have one TFS server that everyone access's. If you are looking for a credible Sync solution then the Integration Platform is not it. Look instead to TaskTop...

Comment: Any way you cut it your will need a very good consultant to set this up and it will be horrendously expensive. Cheap option... One TFS server.